# Clippy redundant allocation lint

Tags: rust, static-analysis, rust-clippy

So I have this trait and a struct that implements it:

```rust
trait Trait {
    fn foo(&self) -> u64;
}

/// No Copy trait supported because it's expensive
struct Expensive {
    id: u64,
}

impl Trait for Expensive {
    fn foo(&self) -> u64 {
        self.id
    }
}
```

I have another structure that I wish to be global, that contains the trait:

```rust
struct Cheap {
    pub item: Box<dyn Trait>,
}

thread_local! {
    static CHEAP: Cheap = Cheap {
        item: Box::new(Expensive {
            id: 4
        })
    }
}

fn trait_item() -> Box<dyn Trait> {
    CHEAP.with(|c| c.item)
}
```

This fails because

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `c.item` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:35:20
   |
35 |     CHEAP.with(|c| c.item)
   |                    ^^^^^^ move occurs because `c.item` has type `std::boxed::Box<dyn Trait>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

It's not really feasible to always do the processing within the `.with(...)` part, because some functions that take in the `Trait` don't care where it comes from. So I try to return a reference to it instead:

```rust
fn trait_item<'a>() -> &'a Box<dyn Trait> {
    CHEAP.with(|c| &c.item)
}
```

This also fails because I cannot send a reference outside of the `with`:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:33:20
   |
33 |     CHEAP.with(|c| &c.item)
   |                    ^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the body at 33:16...
  --> src/main.rs:33:16
   |
33 |     CHEAP.with(|c| &c.item)
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:33:20
   |
33 |     CHEAP.with(|c| &c.item)
   |                    ^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the function body at 32:15...
  --> src/main.rs:32:15
   |
32 | fn trait_item<'a>() -> &'a Box<dyn Trait> {
   |               ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:33:5
   |
33 |     CHEAP.with(|c| &c.item)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So instead I wrap the whole thing in an `Rc` like so:

```rust
struct Cheap {
    pub item: Rc<Box<dyn Trait>>,
}

thread_local! {
    static CHEAP: Cheap = Cheap {
        item: Rc::new(Box::new(Expensive {
            id: 4
        }))
    }
}

fn trait_item() -> Rc<Box<dyn Trait>> {
    CHEAP.with(|c| c.item.clone())
}
```

But now clippy complains:

```
warning: usage of `Rc<Box<T>>`
  --> src/main.rs:41:15
   |
41 |     pub item: Rc<Box<dyn Trait>>,
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: try: `Box<dyn Trait>`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::redundant_allocation)]` on by default
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#redundant_allocation

warning: usage of `Rc<Box<T>>`
  --> src/main.rs:53:20
   |
53 | fn trait_item() -> Rc<Box<dyn Trait>> {
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: try: `Box<dyn Trait>`
   |
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#redundant_allocation

warning: 2 warnings emitted
```

Am I missing something, or is it not actually possible to do what clippy recommends here?

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=821323acce6a3e5cd6058a02e36465f9) | [Relevant Clippy page](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#redundant_allocation)

Comment: Will `Rc<dyn Trait>` work instead? If so, this looks like a misguiding error message, since double indirection can usually be reduced in two ways, but Clippy suggests only one.

Comment: I suspect you have some misunderstanding about what `Copy` does. Implementing `Copy` for a type does not mean it will be copied more often. It does mean that moving the type is semantically a copy, so it might indirectly lead to less efficient code if you decide to pervasively use copies instead of references, but simply implementing `Copy` for something does not have any effect on code generation.

Comment: @Cerberus ah thanks, that did work! Feel free to suggest it as an answer :)

Comment: @trentcl ah maybe I do misunderstand -- if I implement Copy and I forget to make a function argument a reference, will calling that function not cause the struct to be implicitly copied? I want to make sure that I'm never duplicating it

Comment: It would be more accurate to say: if you forget to make a function argument a reference, calling it may cause the argument to be copied whether it is `Copy` or not. (Be aware that large structs are typically passed by pointer according to the ABI, even when semantically passed by value.) Implementing `Copy` could make it more likely that you overlook this mistake, but only if you *also* mistakenly use the struct as if it were `Copy`. I don't find that a compelling argument to make large structs non-`Copy` on principle (although it's also not an argument for making everything `Copy`).

Comment: I only mentioned it because of the comment `No Copy trait supported because it's expensive`. Choosing not to implement `Copy` because you don't want to promise that as part of your public API, or because you want to guarantee that all references to `Expensive` are to the same `static`, is perfectly acceptable. Choosing not to implement `Copy` because copying the struct would be expensive? That's a non sequitur.

Comment: By the way, the misguidance I've mentioned in the first commit seems to have been already fixed, only not landed on stable: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/pull/5899

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap a trait object in a `Rc` as well, since `Rc` is also a pointer.

Therefore if you have `Rc<Box<T>>`, you have two allocations: One for the `T` and one for the `Box` (another pointer, that now is on the heap). Instead, use `Rc<dyn MyTrait>` to only have one allocation.